# Why doesn't this writing to file work?

Tags: python, text-files

I am somewhat new to python and am trying to write to a text file. However, the following code doesn't write the variables to the text file, it just creates an empty text file. Does any know why this is?

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

def appendA ():
 file.write (quantity + ' ')

def appendB ():
 file.write ('\n')
 file.write (crop + ' ')
 file.write (quantity + ' ')

file = open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+')

if crop in file:
 appendA ()
else:
 appendB ()
```

Comment: Specify Python version.

Comment: Python version is 3.5.1

Comment: Are you closing the file when you're done? `file.close()`

Comment: No, would that help?

Comment: Yup. The file data is not necessarily flushed until you `.close`

Comment: You shouldn't be reading files in Python this way in the first place. Use context manager (i.e. `with open(...) as ...`)

Comment: Well it does work now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution you need to be using global variables. And close the file.

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

def appendA ():
 file.write (quantity + ' ')

def appendB ():
 file.write ('\n')
 file.write (crop + ' ')
 file.write (quantity + ' ')

file = open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+')

if crop in file:
 appendA ()
else:
 appendB ()
file.close()
```

EDIT: You don't need global variables for this my mistake...